# Why does this sentence have "to be sold" instead of "to sell"?

Tags: infinitives, passive-voice

> What he did was he translated stories from all of the major European
>   papers ***to be sold to other papers.***

Why the phrase "to be sold to other papers," not "to sell to other papers"?

Comment: The active form "to sell" would imply that "he" (the translator) was doing the selling.  The passive form "to be sold" leaves it unclear whether the translator or someone does the selling.  But sometimes the only answer is 'because that's how the author chose to write it!'.

Comment: My comment above & the answer from @TimLymington were written simultaneously!

Answer (score 1):

It's a difference of connotation, not of grammar. "To sell to other papers" would imply that he sells the stories himself; "to be sold..." means only that somebody (perhaps his agent or an agency) does the selling, and presumably pays 'him' for the labour.